# Randomly choose uniformly distributed numbers in c#

Tags: c#, random

Sorry if this has been asked before. 
I need to randomly select an entry from an NxN matrix, 
Tried to use

```
Random r = new Random();
int x = r.Next0,N-1);
int y = r.Next(0,N-1);

 //some method to operate on x and y
 Open(x,y);
```

But for N=10, I'm only getting about 44 unique pairs of x and y, after that it just repeats the already chosen pairs.

Any reason why? Is it because Im using the same instance of Random?

Comment: Are you trying to have `x` and `y` select random, but different, numbers between 0 and `N`?

Comment: `But for N=10, I'm only getting about 44 unique pairs of x and y` This doesn't sound right. Is this deterministic? Does it happen every time you call whatever method the random object is defined in?

Comment: Well, with an N of 10 you're looking at only a total of 100 possible combinations...  Logically, once you hit around 50% of the pairs, the number of repeated pairs is going to increase exponentially for every new pair...  How many times are you running it to come away with the figure of 44 original pairs/  and how are you tracking that?

Comment: Where are you instantiating your `new Random()`? Make sure you create one and only one `Random` object, then invoke `Next()` on it as many times as you like.  If you create `Random` multiple times in short order, the results won't have random behavior.  See the **Examples** section of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) for an explanation.

Comment: This was me being silly forgetting Random.Next(x,y) being exclusive on the 2nd parameter so Next(0,N-1) never will generate N-1; at most it will generate N-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will in short order output 'Keys = 81' (9*9) so there must be something else wrong with your code.

```
        Random r = new Random();
        int N = 10;
        Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        while (true) {
            int x = r.Next(0, N - 1);
            int y = r.Next(0, N - 1);
            string s = x + "." + y;
            if (!d.ContainsKey(s)) {
                d[s] = s;
                Console.WriteLine("Keys = " + d.Keys.Count);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Oh it was silly that Next(x,y) being exclusive on y so Next(0,N-1) will never generate N-1 hence why I am not getting enough unique pairs.

Comment: OK, but even so you should have gotten 81 combinations for N=10, not 44